# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la fecha de los días hábiles y no inhábiles por rangos en excel C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, net

Como puede sacar los días laborales y no laborales y que si no se labora en ese día se repita el día anterior, ejemplo:
L,M,M,J,V el día viernes debe de tener lo mismo que el sábado y domingo esto conforme a las cantidades que tiene el Excel y esta forma va para los días festivos. ya extraigo la el mes y el año que es lo que me piden pero me falta hacer esto, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor. ya lo estuve intentando pero no me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Chuy. Algunas observaciones para mejorar esta y futuras preguntas:
1. Para el código fuente, no subas imágenes, copia y pega el código (identándolo todo con cuatro espacios https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
2. Limítate a la sección del codigo con la que tienes problemas e indica con comentarios (segùn el lenguaje de programación) detalles del problema como `//Aquí quiero obtener el dia de la semana` 3. Sé puntual en lo que deseas solucionar. Para tu caso creó que bastaria ¿Cómo obtener el dia de la semana de una fecha en C#? La respuesta seria con la propiedad `DayOfTheWeek`

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaración y la ayuda, tendrá algún ejemplo de como lo podría hacer para mi código por favor.